# Access value from another function in php

Tags: php, function, scope

I have a function skipCopy:

```
public function skipCopy($skipcopy){
    $skipcopy1 = $skipcopy;
}
```

Now I wish to use the value in $`skipcopy1` in the copy() function with structure as belows:

```
protected function copy($id, $srcip, $srcusername, $srcpassword, $tgtip, $tgtusername, $tgtpassword, $publish) {
     //use $skipcopy1 here. Do this without passing the value as parameter. as all the parameters in the copy function are mandatory.
 }
```

How can I achieve this.

Both the functions are of same PHP class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*global*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword as mention in another answers or else define that variable as member of the class,

```
protected $skipcopy;
public function skipCopy($skipcopy){
    $this->skipcopy = $skipcopy;
}
protected function copy($id, $srcip, $srcusername, $srcpassword, $tgtip, $tgtusername, $tgtpassword, $publish) {
   echo $this->skipcopy; //You can now access this variable.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define $skipcopy1 as global in copy() function like

```
global $skipcopy1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use global keyword OR you could object to store the values. Use the code below

```
protected function copy($id, $srcip, $srcusername, $srcpassword, $tgtip, $tgtusername, $tgtpassword, $publish) {
global $skipcopy1;
 }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
public function skipCopy($skipcopy){
  global $skipcopy1;
  $skipcopy1 = $skipcopy;
}

protected function copy($id, $srcip, $srcusername, $srcpassword, $tgtip, $tgtusername, $tgtpassword, $publish) {
  global $skipcopy1;
  // use it
}
```

Comment: there is no need for global keyword skiCopy() function

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the 'public' and 'protected' keyword and read that it is class code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this Variable in constructor 
like

```
public function __construct(){
$this -> skipcopy1 = '';
}
```